# JavaFX scrollbar customize. Eliminate extra square, when both scrollbars are activated

Tags: java, css, javafx

I create the next customize scrollbars as in the image below

[image]

I used next CSS

```
.text-area, .text-area .viewport, .text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}

.text-area .scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.text-area .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.text-area .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.text-area .scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color:derive(black, 50%);
}

.text-area .scroll-bar .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color:derive(black, 70%);
}

.text-area .increment-button:hover ,.text-area .decrement-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.text-area .track  {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```

How can I eliminate that extra ugly square, that appears when both scrollbars are activated?

Thank you very much for your time.

**Solution**
Inspired from Lunayah answer

```
.text-area .scroll-pane .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
}
```

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just change color of it, or do you need to remove it completely?

Comment: Color is enough. @Lunayah gave me already the answer. Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name of the 2 squares you see are called .filler and .corner. You can apply whatever color you want to them through css in order to make them not visible. I dont  know if those can be removed.

Ex :   .scroll-bar .filler{ your color}
Ex :   .scroll-bar .corner{ your color}

Comment: That is a great answer! It is indeed what i was looking for. Small remark corner and filler are properties to scroll-pane. If you do not mind I will correct it. Thank you so much for your solution!

Comment: @user2805346  Oh sorry! My mistake. Im glad i was able to help :)

Comment: This answer may be out of date.  To fix this issue with OpenJFX 12.0.2 I used scroll-pane, not scroll-bar.  Example: 
.scroll-pane .corner { 
    -fx-background-color: <my-color>;
    -fx-border-color: <my-color>;
}

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old, but I stumbled on this looking for a solution for the same problem but for the corner in a tree-view, I tried the above with no luck. However, I was able to accomplish it with this selector. Figure it may be helpful to someone else.

```
.tree-view > .virtual-flow > .corner{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```