# JavaFX ScrollPane styling

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to create a black and white ScrollPane in JavaFX. I already created a CSS file, which works pretty fine. Except for this little square:

[image]

Whatever I try, I'm not able to turn it black.
Here is my CSS file:

```
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal, .scroll-bar:vertical{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.increment-button, .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .track,
.scroll-bar:vertical .track{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 5em;
}
```

Is there a way to change the color of this square?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX scrollbar customize. Eliminate extra square, when both scrollbars are activated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737568/javafx-scrollbar-customize-eliminate-extra-square-when-both-scrollbars-are-act)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply add the following selector using the needed color:

```
.scroll-pane > .corner {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use "corner" class.

```
.scroll-pane > .corner {
      -fx-background-color: black;
}
```