# Change the color of the Scrollbar corner in WebView

Tags: css, javafx, scrollbar

I'm working with JavaFX 8 on Windows 10. In a [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) with a dark background, I can see the light grey corner when the scrollbars are visible. `WebView`"manages scrolling automatically." I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23278267/230513), as well as other selectors:

```
.corner {
  -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

And also

```
.corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.scroll-bar > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.scroll-pane > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.scroll-bar .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.scroll-pane .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.web-view .scroll-bar .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.web-view .scroll-pane .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

But it doesn't work. So what could I do?

[image]

Example code: Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<html><body><pre>This is a very very very very very very long string </pre><b>test</b><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p></body></html>");

        webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation("data:,body {  background: black; color: white; } ");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        webView.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
        root.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Test");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

style.css

```
.scroll-bar .track {
    -fx-background-color: black;    
}

.scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: brown;
}

.corner {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

This also has an awful behavior where the scrollbars only appear when I hover with the mouse, but nevermind. This doesn't happen in my main application. **I just want to change the color of the grey square in the corner**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*I can not change the corner color of a ScrollPane in JavaFX*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23278267/230513).

Comment: I'm sorry but no.  That is for a scrollPane and mine is for a webView. I tried all the solutions in that post and they didn't work.
edit: I also tried the selector .web-view > .corner and it didn't work.

Comment: can you plz add html code and create a code snippet

Comment: @XenioGracias I have edited the question to add the code now.

Comment: Try this : `webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation("data: ,body {  background: black; color: white; } ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background: #0c0c0c; } ");`

Comment: @Pagbo Yes! That worked! Thank you so much! May I ask you, how did you come to that solution?

Comment: Actually if the `WebView` component comes from the JavaFX lib, the content is not. You can not style it with the JavaFX css, but in another hand that means you can with the regular `css` :).

Comment: For reference, no problem/change on MacOS. What OS is shown above?

Comment: @trashgod Windows 10.

Comment: @Pagbo Thank you for your explanation but I still have some doubts. I have styled the scrollbars with JavaFX CSS, and the scrollbars are definitely inside the WebView, so why would I style the scrollbar corner with the regular CSS? Don't get me wrong, I know this works, but it's pretty unclear why!

Comment: @user3804769: noted; JavaFX uses [WebKit](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/javafx-webview-overview); `-webkit-scrollbar-corner` is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20232873/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I knew that JavaFX used WebKit, and thank you very much for the link! What I don't understand is why the scrollbars are managed using the JavaFX CSS while the corner formed by the scrollbars is managed using regular CSS. It looks like an oversight by the JavaFX developers.

Comment: You're right. I don't know why the ScrollBar is styleable with JavaFX css and especially why the `corner` is not. I have currently no time to have a deeper look on it, but the problem is interesting. @trashgod are you on JFX 8 or higher ? cause the different behaviour according the OS is also interesting.

Comment: @Pagbo: I've illustrated my results on Mac OS X v10.13.6, Java v1.8.0_201 below. If you get a chance, you might add an answer with your results.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the effect on Mac OS X v10.13.6 with Java v1.8.0_201. Because [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) "manages scrolling automatically" and [JavaFX uses WebKit](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/javafx-webview-overview), @Pagbo [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323956/change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-corner-in-webview?noredirect=1#comment95469652_54323956) using `-webkit-scrollbar-corner`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075981/230513). In another context, @DVarga suggests using `-fx-background-color`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804537/230513). As the effect may be platform/version dependent, I've added a complete example and screenshot for reference. In particular, the lower-right corner is overlain by the vertical scrollbar's decrement button. Stretching the window to hide the vertical scrollbar reveals the horizontal scrollbar's increment button. The corner is always occupied by a scrollbar button or black.

[image]

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<html><body><pre>"
            + "This is a very very very very very very long string<br>"
            + System.getProperty("os.name") + " v"
            + System.getProperty("os.version") + "; Java v"
            + System.getProperty("java.version")
            + "</pre><b>test</b><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p></body></html>");
        webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation("data: ,body "
            + "{ background: black; color: white; } "
            + "::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background: #0c0c0c; } ");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        webView.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black;");
        root.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

style.css

```
.scroll-bar .track {
    -fx-background-color: black;    
}

.scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: brown;
}

.corner {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, on Mac, it seems the horizontal right arrow is not displayed. Actually on windows it is, that's why the bottom right corner appears/exists.

Comment: @Pagbo: Yep; on Mac, the horizontal right arrow (increment button) only appears when the vertical scrollbar auto-hides.