# Javafx change color of two scroll bar joining point

Tags: javafx-8

I have changed color of both vertical and horizontal scroll bars to transparent, vertical and horizontal thumb is also made transparent as well as horizontal and vertical increment and decrement buttons are also made transparent but the point at which both scroll bars meet remains white

[image]

CSS Code:

```css
.scroll-bar .increment-button,.scroll-bar .decrement-button
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
 -fx-background-radius : 0.0em;
}
.scroll-bar .increment-arrow,.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow
{
 -fx-shape : " ";
}
.scroll-bar:vertical
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
.scroll-bar:vertical .track-background
{
 visibility : hidden;
}
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
.scroll-bar:horizontal
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
.scroll-bar:horizontal .track-background
{
 visibility : hidden;
}
.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
.scroll-bar{
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-background-radius: 2em;
   -fx-focus-color: transparent;
   -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
.scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-button,.scroll-bar .decrement-button
{
 -fx-background-color:transparent;
 -fx-background-radius : 0.0em;
}
.scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-arrow,.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow
{
 -fx-shape : " ";
}
```

Comment: I don't think scroll bars actually overlap at that point. Maybe that spot is controlled by some other means besides the scroll bars?

Comment: Does this SO question help? [JavaFX scrollbar customize. Eliminate extra square, when both scrollbars are activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737568/javafx-scrollbar-customize-eliminate-extra-square-when-both-scrollbars-are-act)

Comment: I got the answer by putting .scrollpane > .corner{-fx-background-color: transparent;}, it was answered in some other question